# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I have a dynamic query build with and executed with `TypedQuery<NewsContentBaseInfo>` and one of the fields is CLOB object - `news.stores`. Here is the error I get and I can't find iformation how to solve this:

`java.sql.SQLException: ORA-22835: Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB to RAW conversion`

Here is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT new com.kaufland.newsletter.usecase.newscontent.search.dto.response.NewsContentBaseInfo(news.id, news.uuid, news.dayAndTimeOfPublish, news.title, news.subtitle, news.categoryCountry, news.newsPeriod, to_char(news.stores)) 
FROM com.kaufland.newsletter.domain.content.AbstractNewsContent news 
LEFT OUTER JOIN news.newsLinks newsLinks 
WHERE news.country = :country AND news.status = :status 
AND news.dayAndTimeOfPublish >= :dayAndTimeOfPublishStart 
AND news.dayAndTimeOfPublish <= :dayAndTimeOfPublishEnd 
AND (news.stores LIKE '%'||:storeNumber0||'%') 
AND news.categoryCountry.id in :includeCategoryIds 
AND (LOWER(news.title) LIKE LOWER('%'||:searchText||'%') 
    OR LOWER(news.subtitle) LIKE LOWER('%'||:searchText||'%') 
    OR LOWER(news.text1) LIKE LOWER('%'||:searchTextEscaped||'%') 
    OR LOWER(news.text2) LIKE LOWER('%'||:searchTextEscaped||'%') 
    OR LOWER(news.text3) LIKE LOWER('%'||:searchTextEscaped||'%') 
    OR LOWER(newsLinks.displayText) LIKE LOWER('%'||:searchText||'%')) 
ORDER BY news.dayAndTimeOfPublish DESC
```

Comment: How do you exactly trigger this query? Also add the NewsContentBaseInfo class

Answer (score 2):

The `to_char` function returns a varchar that is limited to 4000 characters. If the CLOB is greater than that you can get this error (depending on the Oracle version).

If you really need an String value you can try with the dbms_lob package (https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_lob.htm#ARPLS600), that can handle more characters.